# Elastic search for .net

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, mssql-jdbc

I want to implement elastic search into my application. I have MS-SQL database.

I have installed Elastic search. It is displaying **You Know, for Search**.
I have added nuget package for Nest. Connected to Elastic. Added one record using Nest. Record is displayed in Kibana.

1. I want to take **SQLdata into Elastic**.
2. Any change in MS-SQL data should reflect into Elastic
3. Search in Elastic for complex fuzzy match.

I stuck for first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I can see from your description that you installed elastic search and its running fine .

For the first step you need to migrate a data present in MS-SQL to Elastic search with the mappings.You can write a python script for this. Python script should map with index and its associated document.

one example for this. 
-- lets consider you have one table in MSSQL eg. Employee table . Then iterate through each row one by one and prepare a document with one row and id would be specific number of a row . insert this in elastic search.

For searching in elastic search - all you need to query on the document using match or compound match as per your requirement .

I have implemented same in python and migrated data from postgres to elastic search.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to know how to keep them in sync. I am just confused with Logstash or Beats(FileBeat...) for windows. I want to keep it simple. Any update on SQL should directly reflect into Elastic. I thought i will use river but it is depricated.

Comment: Unfortunately I worked in older version of elastic search and I had used manual transaction management to do this. Whenever there an update / insert in PostgreSQL , I did same update/insert in Elastic search .

Answer (score 0):

- To send the information to Elastic you should consider the
  alternative of using the REST API, Elastic provides access to a web
  API that allows you to create indexes and also query the records and
  you have no dependency on the Nuget.
- For example to start indexing information in Elastic under an index
  called testIndex , a type called testdata and an Id of 0, you would
  use a similar URI to the following, this URI is from the cloud
  version of Elastic but you should be able to use the same in a hosted
  environment:

  PUT
  https://f1fadb41bd984c72981cb12d79a79203.us-west-1.aws.found.io:9243/testindex/testdata/0
  Payload:

  {
         "user" : "Test",
         "post_date" : "2019-08-07",
         "message" : "Elastic test data"
     }

  To query the Data you would use the following URI:

  GET
  https://f1fadb41bd984c72981cb12d79a79203.us-west-1.aws.found.io:9243/testindex/testdata/0
- You can serialize your C# objects that contain the data from the SQL
  database to JSON and post them to elastic as in the sample payload.
- The process to sync the data can be a timed background job in Asp.net core , a console application scheduled in the event scheduler or event based in your app whenever you detect a successful update to the database.